# First person camera rotation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, three.js

The camera doesn't rotate properly. When I move my mouse in the *x-axis* and *y-axis* the camera appears to flip. I am new to `three.js` and don't know much about the interface.

[image: Camera rotation]

I have seen *mrdoob*'s pointlock controls but i don't understand the use of two separate objects for yaw and pitch. I think he used two objects for this. Is there any other different approach?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>THREEJS</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    let width = innerWidth
    let height = innerHeight

    let scene = new THREE.Scene()
    let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width / height, 0.1, 1000)

    let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
    renderer.setSize(width, height)
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

    let cube = new THREE.Mesh(
      new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1),
      new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xFFFFFF,
        wireframe: false
      }))
    let plane = new THREE.Mesh(
      new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 10, 10),
      new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0x00FF00,
        wireframe: false
      }))
    let light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1.5, 15)

    plane.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0)
    cube.position.set(0, 1, 0)
    light.position.set(0, 10, 0)

    scene.add(cube)
    scene.add(plane)
    scene.add(light)

    addEventListener("resize", () => {
      width = innerWidth
      height = innerHeight
      renderer.setSize(width, height)
      camera.aspect = width / height
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
    })

    camera.position.set(0, 1, 2)

    renderer.domElement.onclick = () =>
      renderer.domElement.requestPointerLock()
    document.addEventListener('pointerlockchange', lockChangeAlert, false);
    document.addEventListener('mozpointerlockchange', lockChangeAlert, false);

    function updatePosition(event) {
      let {
        movementX,
        movementY
      } = event
      let rotateSpeed = 0.002
      camera.rotation.y -= movementX * rotateSpeed
      camera.rotation.x -= movementY * rotateSpeed

      camera.rotation.x = Math.max(-Math.PI / 2, Math.min(camera.rotation.x, Math.PI / 2))
    }

    function lockChangeAlert() {

      if (document.pointerLockElement == renderer.domElement) {
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", updatePosition, false)
      } else {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", updatePosition, false)
      }
    }

    let keys = {}

    function keyDown(event) {
      keys[event.key] = true
    }

    function keyUp(event) {
      delete keys[event.key]
    }

    document.onkeydown = keyDown
    document.onkeyup = keyUp

    function update() {
      let moveSpeed = 0.05

      cube.rotation.x += 0.01
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01

      if (keys["w"]) {
        camera.position.x -= Math.sin(camera.rotation.y) * moveSpeed
        camera.position.z -= Math.cos(camera.rotation.y) * moveSpeed
      }
      if (keys["s"]) {
        camera.position.x += Math.sin(camera.rotation.y) * moveSpeed
        camera.position.z += Math.cos(camera.rotation.y) * moveSpeed
      }

      if (keys["d"]) {

      }
      if (keys["a"]) {

      }


    }

    function draw() {
      renderer.render(scene, camera)
    }

    function loop() {
      update()
      draw()

      requestAnimationFrame(loop)
    }

    loop()
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it uses 2 objects is because of the problem you're describing, which is called "gimbal lock".

With one object, depending on the order of catenation of rotations, you will get a rotation on one axis that locks out rotations on the other axis or causes the other axis to flip.

There is a rotation.order parameter which you can use to get around this (for instance rotation.order = 'YZX', or 'ZYX' instead  of the standard 'XYZ', but then that makes your rotations have a different "order" than the rest of the pipeline, so sometimes a more graceful but slightly less efficient approach is to just use 2 separate objects, one for pitch and one for yaw. Another solution is to use quaternions which don't inherit the problem of gimbal lock.

Gimbal lock is an interesting problem, with an interesting history.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock